# Solution to the ODE, existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a first order equation in $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(t,x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$. Assume the equation $x'=f(t,x)$. Suppose $xf(t,x)<0$ for $|x|>R$  where $R$ is a fixed positive constant number. I have to show that all solutions exist for all $t>0$.

I have seen different solutions here but there is a thing always that I don't quite understand. So they always start $x x'=xf(t,x)<0$ and thus they conclude that $x'<0$ for $x> R$ and $x'>0$ for $x<-R$
Furthermore, they conclude that for $x>R$ the solution cannot pass $x=-R$ and... But that is the part where I get confused. Since they concluded that $x´<0$ for $x>R$, shouldn´t it be that, the solutions shouldn´t pass $x=R$ and not $x=-R$?

Or does anyone maybe has a solution to the entire problem, I am really stuck on it?

Comment: This should be saying that solutions that start at $x(0) > -R$ can't cross $x=-R$ and solutions that start at $x(0) < R$ can't cross $x=R$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I assumed, but I have seen on a few places that they have done it reverse, so I assume it is a typo. And by proving this proposition: "Let $x: [0,T) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and differentiable and satisfies $x' = f(t,x)$, then for any increasing sequence of times $T_n \nearrow T$ we have that $\limsup_{n} |x(T_n) | < \infty$." Is that enough to solve the problem?

Comment: @RobertIsrael but how can we make those assumptions about solutions when we only have a definitive data for $x>R$ and $x<-R$?

Comment: If $x_0 > R$, $x' < 0$ until $x \le R+1$, and then it stays in $[-R,R+1]$ from that time onward.  If $x_0 < -R$, $x' > 0$ until $x \ge -R-1$, and then it stays in $[-1-R,R]$.  If $-R \le x_0 \le R$, then it stays in $[-R, R]$ for all $t \ge 0$.